# How loud was the Concorde's sonic boom at the ground level?

Tags: supersonic, noise, concorde

Before the Concorde was sent into retirement, their supersonic flight paths were restricted to the ocean because of concerns about sonic boom on the ground.

But just how loud was this boom? Was it significantly louder than the noise from a Mach 0.9 airplane?

Comment: The sonic boom of the Space Shuttle generated a pressure of 60 Pa on the ground, from an altitude of 18 km, the Concorde 93 Pa -- that is [133 dB](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-soundlevel.htm) -- from an altitude of 16 km. See this article on [sonic boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom).

Comment: [Concorde was louder than a 0.9 aircraft when it was subsonic!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MCETiKCLhc).  The sonic boom is at 0:58 in the same video.

Comment: @Simon yes but that's take off. I'm wondering how loud it was in-flight.

Comment: Keep watching.  As I said, the boom is at 0:58.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Concorde sonic boom was very much louder (at the same altitude) than flying at M 0.9. 133 dB is above [pain threshold](https://copublications.greenfacts.org/en/hearing-loss-personal-music-player-mp3/figtableboxes/table-1.htm) for most people (discomfort is between 85 and 95 dB SPL and the threshold for pain is between 120 and 140 dB SPL). After pain threshold, no one can say if "this is louder" as ear is saturated. See this [comparison](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/chemsafety/Training/PPETrain/dblevels.htm).

Comment: @mins but didn't the boom last for a split second for an observer on the ground? Basically I'm trying to understand just how bad it would be if supersonic jets were flying around all the time.

Comment: You last comment is a too broad to be answered here (would jets flying around all the time be a pain, so taking into account duration of exposure and mean level), there is a lot of literature online on the topic. Have a look at the last link I posted ("Military jet aircraft take-off from aircraft carrier with afterburner at 50 ft = 130 dB"). 10 dB SPL difference is factor 2 in the ear sensation (sound twice louder).

Comment: @mins please don't answer questions in a comment

Comment: Anecdotally: I remember visiting Hampton Court Palace as a child  on a school trip, which was right below concorde's flight path (into heathrow I suspect). The tour guide had to stop her blurb for a good 90 seconds whilst it flew overhead. That was so far from supersonic, but it was still the loudest thing short of a Vulcan bomber I remember aviation-wise.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm new, but why was this question marked as duplicate. The other question answers whether a sonic boom at 60K' can be heard on the ground. I read that other answer and it doesn't directly answer  Mr @JonathanReez question of whether the Concorde's sonic boom was "significantly louder than the noise from a Mach 0.9 airplane", as is asked in this question.

Comment: @Devil07 I marked it because it directly answered my question.